# running google chrome headless on ec2 ubuntu server

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-ec2

Hello I have a ec2 server, here is the config :

DNS public (IPv4) : ec2-18-191-6-130.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

ID d'AMI : ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200611 (ami-0a63f96e85105c6d3)

When I try to install google chrome to use it headless I have this problem :

```
cat: relocation error: /opt/google/chrome/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

I indicate that I follow this simple tuto to install chrome on my ec2 server :
https://understandingdata.com/install-google-chrome-selenium-ec2-aws/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried to replicate and had same issues as you. But an alternative approach worked for me. You may try that, preferably on fresh ubuntu instance.

**install pre-requsits**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unzip libnss3 python3-pip
```

**install [driver for chrome 83](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/)**

```
cd /tmp/
sudo wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
chromedriver --version
```

**install google-chrome-stable current version (83)**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**check installation**

```
google-chrome-stable --version
```

**install selenium**

```
pip3 install selenium --user
```

The installation is successful in my tests, but I haven't verified if `selenium` works as intended. I only focused on whether `chrome` and `selenium` install.

Comment: I tried your method unfortunatly it changed nothing for me I have the same error

Comment: @ahmedaao Have you tried that on a new ubuntu instance? Previously, it didn't work until I launched clean instance.

Comment: great answer - many thanks

Comment: any luck? how did it go?